# Error running python code via docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pyodbc, docker-image, python-3.9

I have a python code which runs fine to pull data from an API but I am getting issues to run it via docker. I am using pyodbc to load data into SQLServer in my python code. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.2

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unixodbc \
    libpq-dev 

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3","LoadAPI_data.py"]
```

After creating the docker image, when I am trying to run the docker image, I get the following error:

> Error !!!!: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open
> lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0)
> (SQLDriverConnect)")

Can anyone let me know how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: You need to install the SQL-Server native drivers. This article from MS should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17

Comment: @Mureinik, Thanks for the help but it did not solve the issue. I already had odbc files installed and linked. I still get the same issue when trying to run my code via docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get my code running by updating my dockerfile to run installation of SQL DB as well as python. Here is what my new dockerfile looks like.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \      
    apt-get install -y \    
    libpq-dev \     
    gcc \
    python3-pip \
    unixodbc-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl apt-utils apt-transport-https debconf-utils gcc build-essential g++-5\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated msodbcsql17

RUN pip3 install pyodbc

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt


RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3","LoadAPI_data.py"]
```